# How to iterate over two directories

Tags: ruby

I suspect this is the reason why I might be doing a file by file comparison too many times

I have two directories: `directory1` contains files `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, and `directory2` contains files `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` as well.

```
def process(directory1, directory2)
  Dir.foreach(directory1) do |file1|
    Dir.foreach(directory2) do |file2|
      puts file1 + file2
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this I get:

```
..
...
.foo.txt
.bar.txt
...
....
..foo.txt
..bar.txt
foo.txt.
foo.txt..
foo.txtfoo.txt
foo.txtbar.txt
bar.txt.
bar.txt..
bar.txtfoo.txt
bar.txtbar.txt
```

It should be only printing four names. Is my loop wrong?

Comment: When you `ls` these directories, do you see exactly 2 files in each?

Comment: why is the second `.each` block in the first loop? Shouldn't you just separate them?

Comment: Why would it only print four names? For each file in dir1 you concat each file in dir2. n*n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question in your title you can iterator over 2 directories using [`Dir::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) e.g.

```
Dir['/directory1/*','/directory2/*']
```

This will return an `Array` of the files and directories located directly under `/directory1` and `/directory2`. **Also this will ignore dot files.**

See [`Dir#glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) for additional pattern options like recursion (`**`).

Comment: That line solved my problem. Now I can make file comparisons between two directories without doing it twice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KevinR. glad it helped as your title and your actual post did not seem to line up exactly. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

A little indentation makes the problem a little clearer:

```
def process(directory1, directory2)
  Dir.foreach(directory1) do |file1|
    Dir.foreach(directory2) do |file2|
      puts file1 + file2
    end
  end
end
```

For each item in `directory1`, you're printing each item in `directory2`.

I'm not entirely sure how you're trying to use these files or why you're adding the names together in your example, but splitting these into 2 separate loops would be enough to hit each file once.

The other part that may be surprising here is that "." and ".." appear as files when you loop over these directories. That's because "." is a placeholder file that represents the current directory and ".." represents the parent directory just like when you're using a command line, but Ruby also includes them when you enumerate directories this way.

Comment: I did something similar in python and it worked. What I've been trying to do is take files from directory1 (the baseline) and compare then with files from directory2 (the benchmark). It works at first-- it takes foo from directory1 and compares it with foo from directory2, and bar from directory1, and then compares it with bar from directory2)-- But then does same exact process but this time treats the files from directory2 as the baseline. I've suspected my problem is this loop.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, there are also the `.` and `..` files in a directory.

By having `foo.txt` and `bar.txt`, you actually have `4` files in both the directories.

That is why your loop is printing `16` filenames as `4x4=16`

You can confirm this by executing the `ls -a` command inside either of the directories.